# Printing in Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports-2010

I have a project written in C# in VS2010. I am attempting to print a barcode but am having an issue. The barcode print page is located in a crystal report.

```
The bar code field has the formula that equals *25664A-1$1%0/A* which is correct. 

It is in the font - SKANDATA C39. 
When it prints, the rest of the report prints correctly but where the barcode should show, it instead shows- *25664A-1$1%0/A* .
```

Is this due to a wrong font? I need to get this to print the barcode instead of the numbers. It is something specifically wrong with the barcode field since the rest of the report works/prints fine and the formula extracts the correct data.

Any help would be appreciated? If you need more information let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded a new barcode font - C39hrp24dhtt0 (from http://www.free-fonts.com/font/c39.html)

Simply changed my old font to my new font (SKANDATA C39 to C39hrp24dhtt0) (in format editor - font tab) and it now prints the barcode and scans perfectly. Had to make changes to the font size to get the same appearance but after that it works properly.